# Prestashop not working with my JS code

Tags: jquery, prestashop

in Prestashop 1.5.x my slider is not working. However in a simple HTML page it works.

I found that the problem is with this Jquery code:

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#demo1').skdslider ({delay:5000, animationSpeed: 2000,showNextPrev:true,showPlayButton:true,autoSlide:true,animationType:'fading'});

            $('#responsive').change(function(){
              $('#responsive_wrapper').width($(this).val());
            });

        });
```

when i place this code on my page, after refreshing the page it goes WHITE. If I delete it the page opens.

the problem is in this:

```
$('#demo1').skdslider ({delay:5000, animationSpeed: 2000,showNextPrev:true,showPlayButton:true,autoSlide:true,animationType:'fading'});
```

Why prestashop dont like it? Is there anything I can change in order to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the quotes. You should try this:

`$('#demo1').skdslider ({'delay':5000,'animationSpeed': 2000,'showNextPrev':true,'showPlayButton':true,'autoSlide':true,'animationType':'fading'});`